# Apache custom_log is commented out but Apache still outputs access_log

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, logging, httpd

I Commented out custom_log in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but Apache still outputs access_log in `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

How can I disable access_log?

Comment: Did you reload the server configuration after commenting it out?

Comment: Yes I did, actually I disabled CustomLog in my Virtualhost but there is no log option pointing to `/var/log/httpd/access_log` in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this and see if it helps you or not.

lsof | grep /var/log/httpd/access_log

Once you get the pid, grep it with ps and see the time, is it running after service reload ?

This may help to see if the path it still accessed by the application (even after reload)

Thanks